# Bootstrap and expanding menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Default behavior of bootstrap navbar dropdown is regular dropdown that goes over the content. But what if I want to make it like this website when you click directory:

**Collapsed**:

[image: Collapsed]

**Expanded**:

[image: Expanded]

You see how div is expanded. Its like bootstrap menu but on mobile view. So I want on [my site](http://mobilecommz.com/fbcode/) when I hover over menu item, expand whole header section.

Is that possible in bootstrap?

Comment: It's possible but why would you want the whole page to drop down when you only have a very narrow menu to show?

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle the visibility of any content with [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

For example, if you're navbar had the following link:

```
<li><a href="#" >Directory <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
```

You could add `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"` like this:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
    Directory <span class="caret"></span>
</a></li>
```

And then include the dropdown menu you want like this:

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Expander Stuff
</div>
```

### [Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kz655/)

**Collapsed**:

[image: Collapsed]

**Expanded**:

[image: Expanded]

**Note**: I would **not** implement this on hover because it ignores mobile users.  You can easily implement the functionality on click.  If you truly want hover, then you'll have to add some extra handling.

Comment: Thanks everyone. KyleMit can i maybe open all three menus at same time on one click for example http://mobilecommz.com/fbcode/  and click on WHO and open all three menus under who,what,where. Right now it opens just menu under certain item. I know i can make div #demodesktop and put all items there in 3 column but then i will not have same structure for mobile view. I dont wnt to double the menu and make one for mobile and one for desktop. So is it possible on WHO click to open al three submenus expanding (mobile should open just subitem under parent).

Comment: @MitrovicSrdjan, couple notes: My first thought would be wrap all the dropdowns in a single `div` and target that with the collapse function. 2nd, please refrain from [linking directly to the site you're working on](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).  It's too much code for others to easily go through, and it's likely to change which means future visitors will get less value from your question.  Finally, I'm having a little bit of a hard time following what you want. I suggest accepting this answer as it solves this question, and opening another with a working demo in jsfiddle.